# Cannot get image to show up in Java

Tags: java, swing, paint

I'm doing a SwingBot and can't figure out how to get the image to appear. It compiles fine, but isn't visible. What am I doing wrong? [This is my image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avwbx.png) It is in a folder called "images" in the same directory as my code java files.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class SwingBot
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    // contruction of new JFrame object
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    // mutators
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setTitle("SwingBot");

    // program ends when window closes
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Robot r = new Robot();

    frame.add(r);

    // voila!
    frame.setVisible(true);


    // your Scanner-based command loop goes here

    int noend = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter Commands");
    while(noend == 0)
    {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String command = input.next();

    if(command.equals("left"))
        r.moveBot(10,0);

    if(command.equals("right"))
        r.moveBot(-10,0);

    if(command.equals("down"))
        r.moveBot(0,10);

    if(command.equals("up"))
        r.moveBot(0,-10);

    // call methods on the Robot instance like w.moveBot(10,10) in response to
    // user input



 }
```

}

```
public static class Robot extends JComponent
{
    private Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10,10);
    private BufferedImage image;

    public void ImagePanel()
    {
        try
        {                
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("images/flower.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            // handle exception...
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;


        // set the color
        //g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);




        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);


    }


    public void moveBot(int x, int y)
    {
        // move the rectangle 
        rect.translate(x,y);

        // redraw the window
        repaint();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Try using `getClass().getResource("images/flower.png")` or `getClass().getResource("/images/flower.png")` and call `super.paintComponent` before doing any custom painting and use `this` as the image observer parameter to `drawImage`

Comment: What exactly are you doing in your exception handling? Is an exception being thrown without you even knowing because you aren't doing anything in the 'catch' block?

Comment: @John I copied that from another StackOverflow answer. I thought it had to be included. Sorry. I'm new to all this.

Comment: Replace the `//handle exception...` with `ex.printStackTrace();` and check for console output that looks like an error.

Comment: @John Did not get any errors. Ran program. Still nothing showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was easily overlooked, just because it is so weird. You have a method `ImagePanel()`. I think it's safe to assume that the code you got this from `ImagePanel` was the class and `ImagePanel()` was the constructor and you just added the `void` because you were getting an error saying the method needs a return type.

What you should have done instead was make `public ImagePanel()` into `public Robot()` so your `Robot` class has a constructor. Currently you instantiate `Robot` but the image is never initializes because the *method* `ImagePanel()` is never called.

1. You *may* need to go over some basic on [**what is a Constructor**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)
2. Change the `public void ImagePanel()` to `public Robot()`
3. Don't loaded images from `File` objects. Load them through the class path, using `Robot.class.getResource("path/to/image.png")`. See info at [**Embedded Resources**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info)
4. You should call `super.paintComponent` in your `paintComponent` method

   ```
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
   }
   ```
5. When painting, you should override `getPreferredSize()` of your `JComponent` so the component has a preferred size, then you can just `pack()` your frame.

   ```
   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
       return new Dimension(width, height);
   }
   ```
6. Run Swing app from the Event Dispatch Thread but using `SwingUtilities.invokLater`. See [**Initial Thread**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
           public void run() {

           }
       });
   }
   ```

---

See example below

**UPDATE**

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class SwingBot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new Robot());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class Robot extends JComponent {
        BufferedImage img;

        public Robot() {
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(Robot.class.getResource("/images/android.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 300, this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }
    }
}
```

File Structure

```
ProjectRoot
         src
            somepackage
                 SwingBot.java
            images
                 android.jpg
```

Comment: NOTE: use `"/images/flower.png"` as your path for `getResource()` and make sure your `images` folder is a direct child of the `src`

Comment: This is great, but you removed the whole "Move the Rectangle" thing. How can you make the Image act as something that can be translated?

Comment: I removed it because it's not related to your particular posted question. please accept(the check mark) this answer, if it got your image to appear, and ask another question here on SO related to image rotation.

Comment: Fair enough. I will do so.